# Multiple Cmake_Prefix_Paths from ExternalProject

Tags: cmake, external-project

So, if I'm running cmake from the command line...

```
cmake .. "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=path1;path2"
```

This works fine. But if I try to do the same thing from a cmake-based ExternalProject...

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    epname
    URL https://some.url
    CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=path1;path2"
)
```

Then this does *not* work. The CMakeCache generated only has path1 but not path2. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I tried `$<SEMICOLON>` and that did the trick.